# Python - dictionary print the key as many times as his value

Tags: python, dictionary, key

I want to print out all the letters in my dictionary (seen at the last line of my code) the problem is that the output is  *aqlmui* now. But as you guys can see the l in my dictionary is having a value of 2 so I want to print that out 2 times. so the output of my program should be: aqllmui.

Help would be appreciated a lot! :)

```
def display_hand(hand):

    row = ''
    for letter in hand:
        row += letter

       #I think i need to put an if statement here but I just don't know how to do it

    print row


display_hand({'a':1, 'q':1, 'l':2, 'm':1, 'u':1, 'i':1})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also try `print "".join(k*v for (k,v) in s.iteritems())`.

Here `k*v for (k,v) in s.iteritems()` returns a list of `key*value` like `["a","i","m","ll","q","u"]` and `"".join(list)` will join that list to make a string.

Answer (score 1):

just do:

```
row += letter * hand[letter]
```

Comment: works for me. It seems very strange that multiply char by int returns string.. is it the way python define this __mul__ (multiply) function?

Comment: Yes. That's one of python's core principles that the basic operators are overloaded very often. There's also `[4,5] * 2 == [4,5,4,5]`, for example. (Hair splitting comment: there's no char type in python, that's just a one-character `str`.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use string/int multiplication to perform multiple concatenations

```
for letter in hand:
    row += letter * hand[letter]
```

Or a little more clearly and efficiently:

```
for letter, count in hand.iteritems():  # Use hand.items() in Python 3
    row += letter * count
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, this was the most straightforward answer I could've found

```
def display_hand(hand: dict[str, int]) -> None:
    for letter in hand.keys():
        for i in range(hand[letter]):
            print(letter, end=" ")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).